# Is there any way to combine the product of two univariate integrals into a single integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Can two separate integrals but multiplied together in the end by integrated as a product once instead?  In other words, does
$$ \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x \right)\cdot\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)\mathrm{d}x \right) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x$$ holds?

I know we have
$$ \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x \right)\cdot\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)\mathrm{d}x \right)\\
= \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{d}x \cdot\left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)\mathrm{d}x \right)\right)\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x) \cdot g(\tilde{x})\mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}\tilde{x}.$$

By typing this, I realize this may be a bit of a tall ask, so I'll ask if there is an other way to combine the product of two univariate integrals into a single integral.  If so, why?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Well thanks for the direct answer :)

Comment: $\exp(-|x|)$ is a counterexample

Comment: Yes but is there a true variation ?  What if $f(x),g(x)>0$ ?  Or if $f$,$g$ are monotonic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample:

$f$ prescribed by $x\mapsto1$ if $x\in(0,1)$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise.

$g$ prescribed by $x\mapsto1$ if $x\in(1,2)$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise.

The product of $f$ and $g$ is the zerofunction and: $$\int f(x)dx.\int g(x)dx=1.1\neq0=\int f(x).g(x)dx$$

Comment: Yeah, as I said it was a tall call...